# Is there a php echo/print equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, echo

Say I want to print html from inside a script tag.

A source like this

```
<div>foo</div>
<script>
print('<div>Print this after the script tag</div>');
</script>
<div>bar</div>
```

should look something like this in browser after the script has run

```
<div>foo</div>
<script>
print('<div>Print this after the script tag</div>');
</script>
<div>Print this after the script tag</div>
<div>bar</div>
```

I could write my own code for this purpose but since this looks to me like a very simple problem, I'm guessing either I've missed something or my thinking is flawed in some way and printing is left out intentionally.

Also, somewhat related: I'd like to know if a script is (or can be made) aware of the script tags surrounding it. With this information it would be much easier to find the position for the printed html code to be injected into, assuming it's not highly discouraged.

To clarify: I don't need you to write a print function for me. I only need to know if a native method to achieve this exists and I've missed it or alternatively the reason it shouldn't be done.

**EDIT**
I realized that I didn't think the question through.

I got my facts straight and now almost everything seems to be working. I should've originally mentioned that the print function was needed inside templates - I'm working on a template engine experiment. I managed to work it out by separating scripts from plain html and concatenating the split html sans scripts with script output.

As I was writing the code I noticed that everything wouldn't go so smooth because of the asynchronous nature of js. I guess I was expecting to be able to do any kind of js magic in templates, just like I could in php. Seems like actually supporting async code in a fool-proof manner inside templates will require some more thought.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to use `document.write()`

```
<div>foo</div>
<script>
document.write('<div>Print this after the script tag</div>');
</script>
<div>bar</div>
```

Note that this will only work if you are in the process of writing the document.  Once the document has been rendered, calling `document.write()` will clear the document and start writing a new one.  Please refer to other answers provided to this question if this is your use case.

Comment: Ah, I tried document.write() in firebug's script panel and it always cleared the page before writing. It seems to work within the actual page code. Thanks!

Comment: ...and after a little more testing it still clears the page when called outside the initial page render.

Comment: @Pichan: Yes, exactly. While the document is being written, `document.write` writes into it. Once it's done being written, `document.write` creates a *new* document and writes into *that*. (If you think about it, it makes sense that `document.write` can't write into an existing complete document. The PHP equivalent would be calling `echo` after the client has downloaded the whole page and disconnected. Though I admit, the behavior of creating a new document is a bit strange; it might make more sense for it to simply not do anything.)

Comment: Answer accepted. Although I didn't get what I needed, this was closest to one would guess I was after with my accidentally vague and not-so-well thought question. I'll be updating it tomorrow.

Comment: -1: Using document.write() is a very bad way to inject content into a page. It blocks page rendering (or as you've discovered resets it). A much better solution is to set the innerHTML of a span or div element.

Answer (score 32):

You can use **document.write**, however it's not a good practice, it may clear the entire page depends on when it's being executed.

You should use `Element.innerHtml` like this:

```
<div>foo</div>
<span id="insertHere"></span>
<div>bar</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('insertHere').innerHTML = '<div>Print this after the script tag</div>';
</script>
```

Comment: I know this is an old post,  but I found that using `document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = 'your changes here';`
also works and seems simpler to me  (just in case anyone else walks in here from a google search like I did..)

Comment: @Partack It's a habit, I don't like writing long statement, and by creating a variable I can re-use it later. If you don't need to re-use the element, your style of writing works fine.

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
function echo(content) {  
    var e = document.createElement("p");
    e.innerHTML = content;
    document.currentScript.parentElement.replaceChild(document.currentScript, e);
}
```

which will replace the currently executing script who called the echo function with the text in the content argument.

Comment: this works great, but pls modify it a bit: docment => document and remove e.hidden = true; THANKS!

Comment: The best answer so far, must definitely be pinned.

Comment: Great answer. <span> instead <p> could be an improvement as <p> may imply default CSS classes

Answer (score 5):

```
// usage: log('inside coolFunc',this,arguments);
// http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/
window.log = function(){
  log.history = log.history || [];   // store logs to an array for reference
  log.history.push(arguments);
  if(this.console){
    console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
  }
};
```

Using [window.log](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/) will allow you to perform the same action as console.log, but it checks if the browser you are using has the ability to use console.log first, so as not to error out for compatibility reasons (IE 6, etc.).

Comment: Lol'd at the first paragraph. Sadly I don't need this for debug purposes.

Comment: Bummer! (For future viewers: Use this, then to bring up your console in FF, IE, or Chrome, hit `F12`).

Comment: `<Ctrl>`+`<Shift>`+`<J>` in Chrome is preferable over `<F12>` to me.

Answer (score 1):

this is an another way:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Echo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #result{
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        min-height: 250px;
        max-height: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" lang="ja">
    function start(){
        function echo(text){
            lastResultAreaText = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
            resultArea = document.getElementById('result');
            if(lastResultAreaText==""){
                resultArea.innerHTML=text;
            }
            else{
                resultArea.innerHTML=lastResultAreaText+"</br>"+text;
            }
        }

        echo("Hello World!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
<pre id="result"></pre> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

From  [w3school's page on JavaScript output](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp),

> JavaScript can "display" data in different ways:
>
> Writing into an alert box, using window.alert().
>
> Writing into the HTML output using document.write().
>
> Writing into an HTML element, using innerHTML.
>
> Writing into the browser console, using console.log().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.write` or even `console.write` (this is good for debugging).

But your best bet and it gives you more control is to use DOM to update the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('element').html('<h1>TEXT TO INSERT</h1>');
```

or

```
$('element').text('TEXT TO INSERT');
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this here is a fine example of what I've always said about how jQuery's affects the js coder population. Please at least mention that the code needs jQuery to run.

Answer (score 0):

We would create our own function in js like echo "Hello world".

```
function echo( ...s ) // rest operator
 { 
   for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++ ) {

    document.write(s[i] + ' '); // quotes for space

   }

 } 

  // Now call to this function like echo

 echo('Hellow', "World");
```

**Note:** (`...`) rest operator dotes for access more parameters in one as object/array, to get value from object/array we should iterate the whole object/array by using for loop, like above and `s` is name i just kept you can write whatever you want.