# Run PHP with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Below is my JavaScript variable and I want to echo it using php on button click.

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="runphp()">Echo Hi</button>
    <script>
    function runphp() {
    var a = "Hi";
    //echo a with php
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side, JS is client-side. You can't run PHP in JS. Use AJAX

Comment: Yes I need help on that

Comment: Since you tagged this with `jquery`, here's [jQuery's .ajax documentation](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I want to use jquery but I can't find how to take a javascript  variable in php script

Comment: *take a javascript variable in php* - you don't.  You take a URL parameter of POST variable.  Don't think of trying to run them "together" - think of them as separate.  Your JS sends some data using its methods and your php receives the data using *its* methods - which are completely different.

Comment: You. Can. Not. That's why I posted the .ajax documentation link. There are examples on that page posting to a `.php` file.

Comment: To not repeat above comments... You can mimic an echo in javascript: [Is there a php echo/print equivalent in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633085/is-there-a-php-echo-print-equivalent-in-javascript)